# Validate new filetype (*.lsr) in PHP (Laravel 5.1)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, tvos

I'm creating a site to upload Parallax images (created by [Apple's Parallax Previewer](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/CreatingParallaxArtwork.html)), but I'm having problems verifying that the uploaded files is in this format.
The format (*.lsr) is a only a couple of days old so there isn't really that much info around about it.

Is there any way I can check if the is of this type? I'm doing this in Laravel 5.1.

Comment: Yes use custom validation in laravel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `$request->file('filename')->getExtension() == '.lsr'` with a custom validation